# Is there a _pipe() function for Windows Phone?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have

```
int from_fd[2], to_fd[2];
BOOST_ASSERT(_pipe(from_fd, 256, O_TEXT) != -1);
```

to redirect standard input/output of a thread to a pipe. It works for a PC. Unfortunately, _pipe doesn't seem to be even defined for Windows Phone. The compiler reports the function can't be found. Is there any other alternative?

I'm trying to forward everything in standard output to a pipe that another thread in the process can read.

Comment: The underlying winapi function, CreatePipe, is not permitted in Phone8 apps.  You'll need to spin your own thread-safe queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows RT do not support pipes. Use Windows sockets instead of pipes for IPC.